# Why does error "Could not find rubygems-bundler" appear when running 'bundle package'

Tags: rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2, bundler

I'm having a similar problem to [Gem::LoadError: Could not find rubygems-bundler (>= 0) amongst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658028/gemloaderror-could-not-find-rubygems-bundler-0-amongst) and I am assuming the bug mentioned there has been fixed.

I am using `bundle package` to put my gems in /vendor/ruby as detailed in Ryan McCreary's excellent workflow ["Vendor Everything Still Applies."](http://ryan.mcgeary.org/2011/02/09/vendor-everything-still-applies/)

The error when I run `bundle package` is:

```
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/brad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.1.0/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb":
Could not find rubygems-bundler (>= 0) amongst
[actionmailer-3.2.8, actionpack-3.2.8, activemodel-3.2.8, activerecord-3.2.8, activeresource-3.2.8, activesupport-3.2.8, addressable-2.3.2, arel-3.0.2, bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1, bootstrap-sass-2.1.0.1, builder-3.0.4, cancan-1.6.8, capybara-1.1.2, childprocess-0.3.6, coffee-rails-3.2.2, coffee-script-2.2.0, coffee-script-source-1.3.3, cucumber-1.2.1, cucumber-rails-1.3.0, daemons-1.1.9, database_cleaner-0.9.1, devise-2.1.2, diff-lcs-1.1.3, email_spec-1.2.1, erubis-2.7.0, eventmachine-1.0.0, execjs-1.4.0, factory_girl-4.1.0, factory_girl_rails-4.1.0, ffi-1.1.5, gherkin-2.11.5, haml-3.1.7, haml-rails-0.3.5, hike-1.2.1, hpricot-0.8.6, i18n-0.6.1, journey-1.0.4, jquery-rails-2.1.3, json-1.7.5, launchy-2.1.2, libwebsocket-0.1.5, mail-2.4.4, mime-types-1.19, multi_json-1.3.6, nokogiri-1.5.5, orm_adapter-0.4.0, polyglot-0.3.3, quiet_assets-1.0.1, rack-1.4.1, rack-cache-1.2, rack-ssl-1.3.2, rack-test-0.6.2, rails-3.2.8, railties-3.2.8, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.12, rolify-3.2.0, rspec-2.11.0, rspec-core-2.11.1, rspec-expectations-2.11.3, rspec-mocks-2.11.3, rspec-rails-2.11.4, ruby_parser-2.3.1, rubyzip-0.9.9, sass-3.2.1, sass-rails-3.2.5, selenium-webdriver-2.25.0, sexp_processor-3.2.0, simple_form-2.0.4, sprockets-2.1.3, sqlite3-1.3.6, thin-1.5.0, thor-0.16.0, tilt-1.3.3, treetop-1.4.11, tzinfo-0.3.33, uglifier-1.3.0, warden-1.2.1, xpath-0.1.4] (Gem::LoadError)
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or how to fix it; that is, *why* is bundler looking for rubygems-bundler when I run `bundle package`?  Although this is shown as an 'error' (not warning), my bundle seems to be packaged just fine.

When I include `gem 'rubygems-bundler'` in my Gemfile the error goes away, but I'm not sure why I need to do this.

(Btw, this app was initially created using the rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan option for the awesome [RailsComposer by Daniel Kehoe](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/).)

Comment: Have you ran `bundle install` before running `bundle package`?

Comment: Yes, definitely.  `bundle install` first, then `bundle package`.  The only way this doesn't show up is when I add the `gem 'rubygems-bundler'` line in my Gemfile.  I've never needed to do this before.  (Sorry for the delay, I was off-grid for 5 days.)

Comment: Well, yes and no... Yes in that doing what I say above fixes it (adding `gem 'rubygems-bundler'` to my Gemfile makes the error go away).  No, in that my original question I wanted answered was: Why do I need to do that?  I have never needed to before.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:
 `gem install rails -v 'your version'`